# How to import data from other sheet and list them?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I have `Sheet1` and `Sheet2`in the same document. In `Sheet1` from Row 2 (A2~ZX2) there are names. At Row 5 (A5~ZX5) there are checkboxes with custom values set to either 1 for checked, 0 for unchecked.

At `Sheet2` I want to load `Sheet1`'s A2~ZX2 values where their checkbox is unchecked.

I figured out that `=Sheet1!$A1` can load from another sheet, but I don't know how to make as a list that automatically filters checkbox value.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that you need Sheet 2.  Use the funnel looking icon to set up a filter on Sheet 1.

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
=transpose(query(transpose(Sheet1!A2:ZX5),"select Col1 where Col4 <> TRUE"))
```

Leave off the outer TRANSPOSE for a list in a column rather than by row as in your source.